# Why am I getting undefined instance in node.js class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am newbie in node.js. I am trying to define a constructor for node.js class which basically fetches data from mongo db. The code for same is as follows

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var mongoHost = 'localHost';
var mongoPort = 27017;

CollectionDriver = function(db) {
    this.db = db;
    console.log("Collection drive has been set");
};

CollectionDriver = function() {
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort));
    mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
        if (!mongoClient || err) {
            console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
            process.exit(1);
        }
        var db1 = mongoClient.db("Quiz");
        this.db = db1;
        console.log("Set Collection Driver by default");
    });
};

CollectionDriver.prototype.getCollection = function(collectionName, callback) {
    this.db.collection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) callback(error);
        else callback(null, the_collection);
    });
};
//find all objects for a collection
CollectionDriver.prototype.findAll = function(collectionName, obj, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) callback(error);
        else {
            the_collection.find(obj).toArray(function(error, results) {
                if (error) callback(error);
                else {
                    console.dir(results);
                    callback(null, results);
                }

            });
        }
    });
};
```

I am trying to use this in other class as follows:

```
CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver;
var collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db);
OtherClassName.prototype.find = function(credentials, callback) {

    collectionDriver.findAll("user_groups", credentials, function(error, results) {

        if (!error) {
            // Do something
        }
    });

    // ...
```

Whenever I try to access find method of Otherclass it says db variable of above class(i.e ConnectionDriver) is undefined. However I could see ConnectionDriver constructor is getting executed correctly and connection to db is opened correctly and `this.db=db1` is also gettining executed.Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you assigning one function to `CollectionDriver`, then immediately overwriting it with a different function?

Comment: I've fixed the indentation/formatting of your code. You're free to use any style you like in your own code, but when asking for help, please use consistent, reasonable indentation.

Comment: @TJCrowder : Thanks for fixing indentation, I was actually trying to implement something like parameterized constructor and default constructor . Interestingly if I instantiate mongodb client instance in otherclass and then pass to parameterized constructor , this works.... but I would like to take care of DB related stuff in one class only so was trying to   implement necessary stuff in default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head and investing(inwasting) a whole day. I realised the issue. Actually `mongoClient.open()` call is an asyncronous call and i return the CollectionDriver object even before opening db/getting db instance.

I solved this problem by moving opening of db call outside constructor and setting instance db . The modified code is as follows :

```
var db = null;
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
    if (!mongoClient || err) {
        console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
        process.exit(1);
    }
    db = mongoClient.db("Quiz");

});

CollectionDriver = function() {
console.log("Set Collection Driver by default");
};
```

The above code seem to work , however when I assign db instance to `this.db` rather than explicitly declaring a variable as done above , I get same undefined/null error(when i initialise db variable to null). Any thoughts why this behavior ??

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered but I believe the correct answer for this is, `this` gets redefined in function calls. Inside the callback function to open, this now points to the function. The way around this is to use ES6 arrow functions, if you're on node 4+.

```
collectionDriver = function() {
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort));
mongoClient.open((err, mongoClient) => {
    if (!mongoClient || err) {
        console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
        process.exit(1);
    }
    var db1 = mongoClient.db("Quiz");
    this.db = db1;
    console.log("Set Collection Driver by default");
});
```

Note: the `function (err, mongoClient) {` is changed to `(err, mongoClient) => {`

`this` then behaves as expected.